# Proper spelling of "presentmodalviewcontrolle" tag too long

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

So this exists:

[presentmodalviewcontrolle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presentmodalviewcontrolle)

Can we either kill it or spell it correctly?

Comment: Spelling it correctly is 26 characters; the max is 25. What if we just used `modalviewcontroller` instead?

Comment: Plus one for that solution ;)

Comment: My *gut* instinct was to roll this back but now I see what you di

Comment: I'd simply burninate the tag. We do *not* need a tag for each damn method of a single class. In fact I doubt we need a tag for every single class of a framework...

Comment: @Bakuriu I agree that we don't need a tag for every method.  That would be absurd!  But getting rid of many class tags is also extreme, since there's a big difference between, say, a date picker, a slider, and a text field.  We can't just broadly lump everything under `UIKit` or `iOS`.

Comment: The fact that it's 3 years old (iOS 6) plays a factor too... And that removing it won't cripple discovery at all, since I myself encountered that question when searching for the content not the tag.

Comment: I demand a tag for [SimpleBeanFactoryAwareAspectInstanceFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/config/SimpleBeanFactoryAwareAspectInstanceFactory.html)!

Comment: @Undo Surely there is already an MVC tag? Edit: Oh wow, the person who named this part of whatever language it is is a *moron*.

Comment: @PetahChristian Then use tags like `datepicker`, `slider` and `textfield`? I don’t see a reason why we need to have iOS specific tags for those with `UI` prefixed. Even a `UITextField` is still a text field. And since it’s usually accompanied by an `ios` tag, it’s pretty clear too.

Comment: thattaghasshittonsofquest

Comment: Just for passers-by: please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Why do people create tags for methods like these in the first place? I can't comprehend the logic; are there a bunch of `presentModalViewController` experts going around answering `presentModalViewController` questions? I seriously doubt it; this tag is too fine-grained to be useful to begin with.

If a question is primarily about the behaviour of a particular method, then that method's name belongs in the *title*. And if some of these questions *aren't* primarily about `presentModalViewController`, then what value is there to tagging the question with it at all?

I suspect this tag can be burninated and nobody would ever miss it.

Comment: Agree 100%. In fact even a tag for a class is often too fine-grained. Tags should categorize the concepts, not the implementation details used.

Comment: *I suspect this tag can be burninated and nobody would ever miss it.* No one would miss it now, since it's no longer supported, but back in the day, it would have made it a lot more difficult to find specific answers if the only tag for any view controller method had to be [tag:uiviewcontroller].

Comment: @Bakuriu There's a significant difference between setting the title for a [tag:uibutton] and a [tag:uiviewcontroller].  Are you suggesting that both questions should only be tagged [tag:title]?

Comment: @PetahChristian `title` is also a worthless tag. What's wrong with just tagging the question `ios` and letting people see that it's about `UIButton`s or `UIViewController`s via its title?

Comment: I'd say because iOS is made up of over a hundred frameworks, perhaps totaling tens of thousands of methods.  There's no way you could find an answer if all you had to rely on is a (commonly) poorly written title to a problem. Tags aren't meant to be in titles.

Comment: @PetahChristian lets all agree that titles should be descriptive. If that means that you need to include certain tags in a non tag manner (ie. "tag - title" no, but "title in tag for title" yes), is ok to include as many keywords as they are needed.

Answer (score 4):

[presentmodalviewcontrolle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presentmodalviewcontrolle) has 479 questions. The method been deprecated as of iOS 6 and replaced by `presentViewController`.

These particular tags already exist:

- [modalviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modalviewcontroller) 1,106 questions

  This tag is not specific to iOS, and (at a quick glance) is used by other platforms such as ASP.NET and AngularJS.
- [presentviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presentviewcontroller) 247 questions

While the original tag looks odd (due to the 25-character limitation), I'd favor keeping it.

But if retagging were to be done, I'd suggest carefully ensuring that questions are tagged by a platform before anyone happened to migrate platform-specific [presentmodalviewcontrolle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presentmodalviewcontrolle) historical questions to a platform-agnostic [modalviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modalviewcontroller) tag.

Comment: [These](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpresentviewcontroller%5D+-%5Biphone*%5D+-%5Bios*%5D+-%5Bitab*%5D+is%3Aq) are the ones under [tag:presentviewcontroller] needing some manual editing-love before synonymizing. [These](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpresentmodalviewcontrolle%5D+-%5Bios*%5D+-%5Biphone*%5D+-%5Bipad*%5D+is%3Aq) are the ones under [tag:presentmodalviewcontrolle].

Comment: @Deduplicator Although not in favor of making a change, I was responding to [Undo's suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315807/presentmodalviewcontrolle-tag#comment300894_315807).  If you're proposing an alternative to synonymize [tag:presentmodalviewcontrolle] into [tag:presentviewcontroller], I believe that would be a better choice.

Comment: Considering how many people upgrade to the latest model of iDevices every year, it stands to reason we should probably just get rid of any iOS version-specific tags from n-2+ versions ago... I'm only slightly joking

Comment: "*This tag is not specific to iOS,..*" -- I tend to think it is. ASP.Net MVC is *model..* not *modal*. Any question marked otherwise are perhaps marked wrong.

Comment: @Abhitalks - There is a modal in Bootstrap/AngularJS though, which is probably where the confusion is happening for that.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/351462), I don't see any reason why this tag can't be renamed to [presentmodalviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presentmodalviewcontroller).

Comment: Or still burninated because of all the original reasons 